# Unable to modify target capacity of spot fleet in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3, boto

I was using a python lambda function to terminate spot fleet instances using the below code,

```
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
      
    response = client.modify_spot_fleet_request(
        ExcessCapacityTerminationPolicy='default',
        SpotFleetRequestId='sfr-xxxxxxxx-593f-4444-9e99-nnnnnnnnnn',
        TargetCapacity=0
    )
    print(response)
```

but the code throw error like this,

```
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (FleetNotInModifiableState) when calling the ModifySpotFleetRequest operation: Fleet Request: sfr-xxxxxxxx-593f-4444-9e99-nnnnnnnnnn is not a modifiable fleet request type.",
  "errorType": "ClientError",
  "requestId": "70e972c1-5d92-4642-93a8-b70cc799e591",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 23, in lambda_handler\n    response = client.modify_spot_fleet_request(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 386, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 705, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}
```

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only modify SF with maintain target set. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-fleet-requests.html#modify-spot-fleet):

> You can't modify a one-time Spot Fleet request. You can only modify a Spot Fleet request if you selected **Maintain target** capacity when you created the Spot Fleet request.